# Visual Studio 2019 not loading references

Tags: c#, .net

I cloned a .net 4.8 project from Azure dev ops, and when I open it, I get a missing reference warning on all the references. See:

How can I resolve all these references? I thought these references come with the project?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you done a package restore?

Comment: No, what is that and how do you do it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#restore-packages-manually-using-visual-studio

Comment: Did you try Build->Rebuild Solution in Visual Studio?

Comment: If Clean Solution/Rebuild solution, restoring packages do not help.
You can try to close Visual Studio, delete bin and obj folders in your project, open Visual Studio and compile solution again

Comment: Son of a gun, package restore actually fixed it!

Comment: Question is why were all these even missing in the first place? I thought some of these like `System` were built into .net.

Comment: They're missing because packages don't get added to source control (or at least, they *shouldn't*, but that wasn't always the case -- lesson learned, thankfully). Whenever you clone a repository, you're going to have to download any packages that are required. It should be a one-time thing, although you will have to download newer versions if someone else upgrades packages.

Comment: The newer (SDK-style) project format uses `<PackageReference>` elements instead of a `packages.config` file. That system caches packages to `%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages`, so if a package has already been cached, even by another project, it'll be available to the project in the newly cloned repository.  There's also support for `<PackageReference>` in the older project style, but switching to it can be tricky.